Who is "my system administrator" on single-account Windows 11 Pro laptop?
Ever since latest Windows 11 Pro update a couple of days ago (now, I am on 10.0.22631 Build 22631) I started experiencing weird (?) messages like: "For your security, some settings are managed by your system administrator" (emphasis mine).
The thing is that I am the only user and the only administrator in this peculiar PC:

Please, help me understand what am I missing in the above picture.
If:

I have the only one account in given PC.
This account is an administrator-type.
My computer is not a part of domain, nor it is connected to any school or company network.

Then who is that "mysterious" my system administrator, who is controlling my PC?
And the most important -- how to fire this guy, kick him off my hardware and regain full control over my own, private PC?
EDIT: I am using a Microsoft Account if that matters.

Do you have a local account or did you sign in with a microsoft account? Also do you use your computer for work, and has your work asked you to setup something on your computer (like added an azure intune account)?

@LPChip I have updated question, thanks. I am using a Microsoft account (as could be suggested by pixelized image and emails address in the screenshot). As wrote a couple of times in the post, this is a totally private a computer, never used for work, never connected to any workplace network. I haven't been asked to install or installed InTune or any other domain, workplace or network controlling software. I am 100% the only user of this computer. These weird messages started to appear after latest Windows Update update (2-3 days ago). Earlier there was no sign of them. Thanks!

The notification is generic. It’s unaware you are an Administrator and is a result of you as an Administrator disabling some related option or feature. These notifications, indicating something was managed by a group policy, have always worked like that. So what’s the real question? Do you want help with identifying and enabling the relevant options or feature necessary to enable and/or disable BitLocker? The other words the same notification is always disabled when a feature or option is controlled by a group policy and when it cannot be changed by a permission elevation request.

@Ramhound its more likely microsoft changed a regsetting as part of being logged in with a microsoft account

@LPChip - Unlikely; The account is still a local account, and is simply linked, to a Microsoft Account. We haven’t reached the time where the account does not exist locally on the machine.

@Ramhound IMHO the question is quite legitimate. Windows claims explicitly that settings are managed by "your system administrator" so an answer to the question who that system administrator actually is should be possible. If the answer is "no-one; that message is bogus" then the ensuing question is of course: "How can I access the settings Windows is denying me with that bogus justification?"

@TilmanSchmidt - I didn’t say the question wasn’t legitimate. The notification is displayed regardless if you are or are not an Administrator on the system and would e displayed for both local and Active Directory users alike. I feel like you are putting words in my mouth that I most definitely have to written

@Ramhound actually, all the message says that there's a registry key in place that normally is used from a GPO, but I've seem it happen that microsoft itself enforces it. For example on a tablet device with windows home, by default, drive encryption is turned on even though bitlocker is not supported on windows 11 home, and you get this very same message.

@Ramhound The depicted notification has appeared a 3-5 days ago, after a latest "Your system will be updated outside office hours". It wasn't there weeks or months ago or never. The question is how to get rid of it and have 100% access to everything, as I had just a couple days ago.

The Settings window is blocking the important information within File Explorer. What was the last cumulative update that was installed? It’s clear you’re running 23H2 (10.0.22631) but unclear the minor build.

Additionally, BitLocker Drive Encryption, provide a screenshot of the group policies would be helpful

This sort of "bug" has been around a long time (https://superuser.com/search?q=some+settings+are+managed) I would guess you may not be able to "make it go away". If you encounter a specific setting you are not allowed to change, THAT is the sort of question we've answered specific to the setting that needs changing.

@Ramhound The situation gets more and more weird as I dig through it. I am 100% positive that there was some major update to my system 5-6 days ago, with forced restart and "install outside working hours", but my Windows Update's history claims that latest update was installed... a month ago: KB5040442 (July 9, 2024). Don't know what to say. The KB5040527 (July 25, 2024) is currently waiting to be downloaded and installed.

@music2myear Your comment would work as a great answer (sort of: "nothing new" + "plenty of examples" + "you won't achieve much in general, must ask specific" + "you can't disable this"). But that won't answer the question about which user Windows is talking about (on single-user system, with mine very own account as the only one). The sub-question is, if that main question is answerable at all. Thanks!

@trejder - That sounds like a horrible answer. There is a deleted question, with the policy I would be interested if it was enforced, but that question is on another device, and I don't have the question handy. I would still be interested knowing which cumlative update you installed a month ago other than KB5040527.

This sort of "bug" has been around a long time (See this list of questions: superuser.com/search?q=some+settings+are+managed) I would guess you may not be able to "make it go away". If you encounter a specific setting you are not allowed to change, THAT is the sort of question we've answered specific to the setting that needs changing.
The thing is, the message INDICATES something different from what the words the message is comprised of communicate. In other words: there isn't a specific account this message is referring to, and what the message really means could be:

Something is minorly broken.
Something is significantly broken.
There's some configuration somewhere blocking one or more of the controls on this page.

That last one is the most common, and thus most likely in your case, scenario.
You may wish to pose another question specifically regarding how to free up/clear/release the setting you are trying to but are currently unable to change.
